# Minecraft Pocket Edition to Minecraft Java - Worlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was building this pretty large build on Minecraft Pocket Edition (iPhone), and now that I started playing Minecraft on my Macbook Pro, It's getting hard for me to build on MCPE. I have tried multiple methods to convert MCPE worlds to MC Java, but all have failed (MCToolChest doesn't work for me since I am running on a Mac, which doesn't support Windows). I really don't want to start over, but I could borrow someone else's Windows laptop to perform MCToolChest, though I'll save that as a last resort. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like this isn't possible for certain versions, although some search results seem to indicate that there have been some tools to do it (like MCCToolChest, which might not be an option as you say).

Comment: @MBraedley It won't work on my MacBook, but I could borrow a Windows device to have it work.